# AspectJ not executing on Junit methods

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, aop, aspectj

Using AOP, I am trying to log test method execution time, but nothing happens when I run a test method.

I've tried to change regex in my pointcut but doesen't seem to be working.

My aspect class:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggableAspect {

  @Pointcut("execution(public * com.mozzartbet.*.*.*Test.*(..))")
  public void publicTestMethod() {}

  @Around("publicTestMethod() && @annotation(loggable)")
  public Object logTestExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Loggable loggable) throws Throwable {
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName());
    StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder(joinPoint.getSignature().getName()).append("()");

    Object result = null;

    try {
      if (loggable.detail()) {
        prefix.append(": ").append(Joiner.on(",").join(joinPoint.getArgs()));
      }
      result = joinPoint.proceed();

      return result;
    } finally {
      long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
      if (loggable.detail()) {
        prefix.append(" -> ").append(result);
      }
      logger.info("{} took {} ms", prefix, t2 - t1);
    }
  }
}
```

My test class:

```java
package com.mozzartbet.gameservice.services.impl;

public class PlayerServiceImplTest extends BaseServiceTest {

@Autowired
  private PlayerService playerService;

@Test
  @Loggable(detail = true)
  public void testInsert() {
    assertThat(playerService.insert(Player.builder().id("foo").build()), is(1));
  }

}
```

Annotation:

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface Loggable {

  boolean detail() default false;

}
```

PlayerService insert method

```java
@Override
  public int insert(Player player) {
    try {
      return playerDao.insert(player);
    } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
      throw new PlayerException(PlayerExceptionCode.DUPLICATED_PLAYER_ID, "ID: %s is duplicated!", player.getId());
    }
  }
```

Dao insert method:

```java
@Override
  public int insert(Player player) {
    return playerMapper.insert(player);
  }
```

I am inserting with mybatis.

Comment: you need to specify the qualified package name of your custom annotation

Comment: It works without package name on other methods, when I tried to add package name, I got an error.

Comment: show your playerService.insert method

Comment: Okay, I've added playerService.insert method's code.

Comment: Does it work on any other test? Have you tried to just use `@annotation(loggable)` or simply `execution(* *(..))` in order to verify that AOP is configured to work at all on tests? Maybe you configured it correctly for application code but not for test code. Let's find that out first before we talk about aspect details.

Answer (score 0):

Your @annotation definition is incorrect.

You should specify the qualified package name of annotation.

```
@Around("publicTestMethod() && @annotation(your_package.Loggable)")
```

Comment: It works without package name on other methods, when I tried to add package name, I got an error.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is incorrect. The OP binds the annotation to an advice parameter, so the reference to the parameter name is correct in his pointcut. Without the parameter binding your answer would be correct.